# Couchbase how to transfer an existing user to a new install

Tags: couchbase

I am working on a script to download all of the user data from one Couchbase database and transfer it to another.  I am having an issue with transferring the user's roles and password data since it is generated by Couchbase and not something I enter in directly.

For example, when I create a new user, I have this data in a file

newuserdata.txt:

```
{
   "name":"myuser",
   "admin_channels":[
      "myorganization",
      "myorganization/auth",
      "myorganization/config"
   ],
   "all_channels":[
      "!",
      "myorganization",
      "myorganization/auth",
      "myorganization/config"
   ],
   "email":"myuser@email.com",
   "password":"password123"
}
```

Then, to insert it:

`curl -sXPUT -H'Content-Type:application/json' -d"@newuserdata.txt" localhost:4985/mydatabase/_user/myuser`

Then when I look up the user in the database:

`select * from my_database where name="myuser"`

I get

```
    "my_database": {
      "admin_channels": {
        "my_organization": 1,
        "my_organization/auth": 1,
        "my_organization/config": 1
      },
      "all_channels": {
        "!": 1,
        "my_organization": 1,
        "my_organization/auth": 1,
        "my_organization/config": 1
      },
      "name": "myuser",
      "passwordhash_bcrypt": "<<hashed password>>",
      "rolesSince": {},
      "sequence": 20
    }
```

When I access it from a url:

`http://localhost:4985/mydatabase/_user/myuser`

```
{"name":"myuser","admin_channels":["myorganization","myorganization/auth","myorganization/config"],"all_channels":["!","myorganization","myorganization/auth","myorganization/config"],"email":"myuser@email.com"}
```

So far, so good.

However, now I want to download this user, preserve their hashed password and data, and transfer this user to a new database.  Basically, I am replicating the organization and all of its users on a new server with a new Couchbase database.

I can pull the user record down to a local file, but I can't insert it into the new database since I don't have a raw text version of the password, only the hashed version.

Is there a command or method that I am missing that allows this to be done?  Or a workaround?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Have you considered joining the new server(s) to the existing cluster and then remove the old servers one by one? in this case you almost don't need to do anything at all.